# User specified parameter to determine which function to call in large loop

Tags: c++, optimization

I am working on a program that has a large loop in the main (several millions of iterations). In the loop there are function calls, but the functions that are called depends on user specified parameters. So a naive solution would be to have conditional statements inside the loop in main to check the user specified parameter (see code snippet). However this does not feel like the best solution since I want my program to be fast (optimization is very important). I have also considered function pointers and virtual functions but these also seems slow for my purpose (function pointers has been my best bet so far since the functions can't be inlined anyways because which function to call is determined during runtime).

I think my problem is best illustrated by an example since I have trouble putting it in words:

```
int func1(params){
  //Do stuff
}

int func2(params){
  //Do other stuff
}

int func3(params){
  //Do different stuff
}    

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  int some_value;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
    if(argv[1] == option_one){
      some_value += func1(params);
    }

    if(argv[1] == option_two){
      some_value += func2(params);
    }
    if(argv[1] == option_three){
      some_value += func3(params);
    }
  }
}
```

This feels like a pretty common problem so is there an effective solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will all three functions be called with the same number and type of arguments? Then how about a table of function pointers, and to the argument checking once at the top, setting an index of the function in the table to be used. Or perhaps save a pointer to the correct function to be used later in the loop.

Comment: If you do not have a lot to do inside the all three functions, make it as an lambda functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude far the functions has the same arguments, I will try to check the table of function pointers solution.

Comment: @JeJo the functions contain a lot of stuff unfortunately and only one argument is passed in argv[] to determine which function to call so it is argv[0] haha yeah 10m arguments would be a hassle :P

Comment: @user1621127 Yes now I understood. I misunderstood it wrong.

Comment: why not use an `unordered_map` with `key` as `option` and `value` as `funcx`

Comment: @Jarod42 You are right, I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it the other way:

```
if (argv[1] == option_one){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        some_value += func1(params);
    }
} else if (argv[1] == option_two){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        some_value += func2(params);
    }
} else if (argv[1] == option_three){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        some_value += func3(params);
    }
}
```

Possibly creating a template function for the loop to avoid repetition.

```
template <typename F>
int my_accumulate(F&& f)
{
    int some_value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10'000'000; ++i) {
        some_value += f(params);
    }
    return some_value;
}
```

and then

```
if (argv[1] == option_one){
    some_value = my_accumulate(&func1);
} else if (argv[1] == option_two){
    some_value = my_accumulate(&func2);
} else if (argv[1] == option_three){
    some_value = my_accumulate(&func3);
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of these functions, more than three (should have mentioned that in the question...) so in the first solution there would be a lot of redundant code. The second looks more like something I wanted, but would there be much overhead in doing it this way? I'll try to time it later today if I got some spare time

Comment: Logically, your hot path is your loop, I expect compiler to inline `func1`, .., `func3` directly in the loop. if it is not done with function pointer, lambda might help (`&func1` -> `[](auto&& params){ return func1(params); }`).

Comment: If there is anything to gain by optimizing the loop (which should be questioned, this looks like a futile micro-optimization), this is the way. Code "redundancy" is really not a concern even if you have hundreds of functions - unless you didn't tell us everything about your loops.